# Getting data between dates is not accurate

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to fetch data between two dates. My query is:

```
select * 
  from TABLE
 where CREATED_DATE >= '11-MAY-2015'
   and CREATED_DATE <= '11-MAY-2015'
```

It doesn't return any value. Though the data is present for 11th May and can be fetched if I give the dates as

```
CREATED_DATE  >= '11-MAY-2015'  and CREATED_DATE <= '12-MAY-2015'
```

Comment: Data type? date or timestamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateType `Date` do have time part also.
When you say `'11-MAY-2015'` its actually `'11-MAY-2015 00:00:00'`

> Date
>  This datatype contains the datetime fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY,
>   HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. It does not have fractional seconds or a
>   time zone.

Try this query

```
select * 
from TABLE
where
CREATED_DATE  >= date '2015-05-11'  and CREATED_DATE < date '2015-05-12'
```

This will be in effect

```
11-MAY-2015 00:00:00 <= CREATED_DATE <  12-MAY-2015 00:00:00
```

Or by using `Trunc` which will ignore the `time` of the date:

```
select * 
from TABLE
where
Trunc(CREATED_DATE) = date '2015-05-11'
```

Edit:  Updated the date field using `date literals`, as `11-MAY-2015` will only work with certain `NLS` settings.. (comment by `@Ben` and `@David Aldridge`)

Comment: Just a note: So the actual condition then should become: `CREATED_DATE  >= '11-MAY-2015'  and CREATED_DATE < '12-MAY-2015'`

Comment: @Silvermind  thanks updated my answer with your comment

Comment: Never compare dates with a string literal.

Comment: This is a really, really, bad idea. It's inextensible - will only work with certain NLS settings and will randomly break depending on your NLS settings as you're not using dates. These are strings.3

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the CREATED_DATE datatype You may need to use the [TO_DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) function. Try this:

```
select * from TABLE where 
CREATED_DATE >= TO_DATE('2015-05-11 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS') 
and CREATED_DATE <= TO_DATE('2015-05-12 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Never** do this:

```
CREATED_DATE >= '11-MAY-2015'
```

The result you get will be dependent on your NLS settings for the server, client, and/or session, as you are comparing a date with a string literal, requiring the string literal to be implicitly converted to a date.

Always convert literals strings to literal dates to do a comparison of this sort. The most simple way is:

```
CREATED_DATE >= date '2015-05-11'
```

... but if you have to accept date strings in another known format then:

```
CREATED_DATE >= To_Date('11-MAY-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

In this case, you probably need to:

```
CREATED_DATE >= date '2015-05-11' and
CREATED_DATE <  date '2015-05-12'
```

Comment: yea dont worry, It was not the exact syntax. I have proper Date format being passed to the query internally. This date was just a copy paste from the UI